# Parallax layer is not showing up in GameScene

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, parallax

Normally I take my action layer.m and in its init method add a call to a parallax method, such as:

```
    [self addScrollingBackgroundWithParallax];
```

where that method is:

```
-(void)addScrollingBackgroundWithParallax {
CGSize screenSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
CGSize levelSize = [[GameManager sharedGameManager]
                    getDimensionsOfCurrentScene];

// 1. Create image (sprite node)
CCSprite *BGLayer1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"chap9_scrolling4.png"];

// 2. Create Parallax Node, Position it 
parallaxNode = [CCParallaxNode node];
[parallaxNode setPosition:ccp(levelSize.width/2.0f,screenSize.height/2.0f)];
float xOffset = 0;
// 3. Add image node to parallax node
[parallaxNode addChild:BGLayer1 z:1 parallaxRatio:ccp(1.0f,1.0f) positionOffset:ccp(0.0f,0.0f)];
xOffset = (levelSize.width/2) * 0.3f;
// 4. Add parallax node to layer
[self addChild:parallaxNode z:1];
```

}

This works fine.  So Im trying to do something somewhat different.  In the game scene class I init the following:

```
-(id)init{
self = [super init];
if (self != nil) {
    // The scene will start out by running layer1
    _layer = [PlaneLevel node];
    [self addChild:_layer z:1];

    //Add eye candy
    layer2 = [Scene2EyeCandy node];
    [self addScrollingBackgroundWithParallax];

}
return self;
```

}

A gamelayer and an eyecandy layer.  I add the gamelayer to the scene but then instead of adding the eyecandy layer to the scene, I call the addScrollingBackgroundWithParallax method which does this:

```
-(void)addScrollingBackgroundWithParallax {
CGSize screenSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
CGSize levelSize = [[GameManager sharedGameManager] getDimensionsOfCurrentScene];
// 1. Creates the parallax node
CCParallaxNode *parallaxNode = [CCParallaxNode node];
// 2. Positions it
[parallaxNode setPosition:ccp(levelSize.width/2.0f,screenSize.height/2.0f)];

float xOffset = 0;
// 3. Adds the eyecandy layer to the parallax node 
[parallaxNode addChild:layer2 z:40 parallaxRatio:ccp(1.0f,1.0f) positionOffset:ccp(0.0f,0.0f)];

xOffset = (levelSize.width/2) * 0.3f;
// 4. Finally add the parallax node to the scene.
[self addChild:parallaxNode z:1];
```

}

But when I run the game I dont get the eyecandy layer at all.

Comment: checklist if a node doesn't show up: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/09/reasons-node-show/

Answer (score 0):

Of cource, you don't. Your code:

```
//Add eye candy
layer2 = [Scene2EyeCandy node];
[self addScrollingBackgroundWithParallax];
```

So where is

```
[self addChild: layer2];
```

?

Comment: In #3 of addScrolling... method.